# Shipping Charges Calculator miss calculation

Tags: java, if-statement, java.util.scanner

The assignment has the following rates: 
Weight of Package Rate per 500 miles shipped
2 pounds or less $1.10
over 2 pounds but not more than 6 pounds $2.20
over 6 pounds but not more than 10 pounds $3.70
over 10 pounds $3.80

The shipping charge per 500 miles are not prorated. For example, if a 2 pound package is shipped 502 miles, the charge would be $2.20. Write a program that ask the user to enter the weight of a package and then display the shipping charges.

My issue is that im getting wrong answers. This is what i got so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ShippingCharges
{
public static void main (String [] args)
{
    double mDrive, rMiles, wPound;

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.print ("Enter Weight of Package: ");
    wPound = keyboard.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("");

    System.out.print ("Enter Miles Driven: ");
    mDrive = keyboard.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("");

    rMiles = mDrive / 500;

    if (wPound <2)
    {
        System.out.println ("You will be charged "+ "$" + Math.ceil(rMiles)*1.10);
    }

    if (wPound >=2 && wPound <6)
    {
        System.out.println ("You will be charged "+ "$" + Math.ceil(rMiles)*2.20);
    }

    if (wPound >=6 && wPound <10)
    {
        System.out.println ("You will be charged "+ "$" + Math.ceil(rMiles)*3.70);
    }

    if (wPound >= 10)
    {
        System.out.println ("You will be charged "+ "$" + Math.ceil(rMiles)*3.80);
    }

}
}
```

Following the example, the program should do 502/500 *2.2 which is 2.2 and the program is showing 4.4. Any suggestion?

Comment: According to the instructions provided, your code should be `if(wPound<=2)` and `if(wPound>2 && wPound<=6)` etc etc. Which btw you could get away with `if(wPound<=2)` and `else if(wPound<=6)` and so on.

Comment: Harold : It works. Should i do the same for the other or just this one?
Calvin: still gives the same answer

Comment: @JonathanSGutierrez Read Calvins answer. He is correct. It should work if you fix your if statements. Keep the Math.ceil the same and try it.

Comment: @Harold My bad, i missplaced something, but works for the example.

Answer (score 1):

Your if statements are the culprit. Following the instructions you provided, the statements should read as follows

```
if (wPound<=2) {
    System.out.println ("You will be charged "+ "$" + Math.ceil(rMiles)*1.10);
}
else if(wPound<=6) {
    System.out.println ("You will be charged "+ "$" + Math.ceil(rMiles)*2.20);
}
else if (wPound<=10) {
    System.out.println ("You will be charged "+ "$" + Math.ceil(rMiles)*3.70);
}
else {
    System.out.println ("You will be charged "+ "$" + Math.ceil(rMiles)*3.80);
}
```

Comment: 1 Last question:  if a value of wPound = 5 shouldnt the 2nd and 3rd statement be true?

Comment: Yes, but using `else if`, it will fall into the first statement that evaluates to true and skip the rest @JonathanSGutierrez

Comment: Thanks for everything! i was a little bit confused about that part.